# Time complexity of 2 different append functions to a linked list?

Tags: python, algorithm, linked-list, append, time-complexity

Suppose you have the following Python functions and assume the normal structure for a linked list:

```
def append(self, element):                                        # Line 1

    new_node = Node(element, None) #2nd arg. is the next_node     # Line 2
    ptr = self.head                                               # Line 3

    if self.size == 0:  # No elements case                        # Line 4
        self.head = new_node                                      # Line 5
        self.tail = new_node                                      # Line 6
        self.size += 1                                            # Line 7
    else:               # 1 or more elements                      # Line 8
        while ptr.next_node != None:                              # Line 9  
            ptr = ptr.next_node                                   # Line 10
        ptr.next_node = new_node                                  # Line 11
        self.tail = new_node                                      # Line 12
        self.size += 1                                            # Line 13
```

The function attempts to append a node to the end of a linked list, while updating relevant values. I want to know the time complexity of the function - ideally, it would be O(c), where c is a constant, but I believe it is O(n).

Analyzing line by line, I can see lines 1-7 and 10-13 are executed once per function call and run in constant time. Lines 8-10, however, would run in linear time since the while loop has to execute n times for n nodes. Moreover, line 10 is also executed n number of times.

Am I correct that the function runs in O(n) time?

Next, consider an alternative function.

```
def append(self, element):                                        # Line 1

    new_node = Node(element, None) #2nd arg. is the next_node     # Line 2
    ptr = self.tail                                               # Line 3

    if self.size == 0:  # No elements case                        # Line 4
        self.head = new_node                                      # Line 5
        self.tail = new_node                                      # Line 6
        self.size += 1                                            # Line 7
    else:               # 1 or more elements                      # Line 8
        ptr.next_node = new_node                                  # Line 9  
        self.tail = new_node                                      # Line 10
        self.size += 1                                            # Line 11
```

Lines 1-11 are all if statements or assignments, which run in constant time, and are executed once per function call. Therefore, this function would run as O(c).

Would it run in O(c) time?

Comment: Yes and yes. Since you're going through the whole linked list just to append at the end, the first one runs in `O(n)` time (if you're appending to the head of the list it has to loop through the whole list to obtain the tail node) whereas the second one just references the `tail` node directly so it will always execute in O(1) time regardless of the list size or what particular node you're appending to. I'd only suggest moving `ptr = self.tail` in the `else...` clause as it makes no sense to obtain a list tail of a zero-size list (and you're not using it, anyway).

Comment: Good call - will do that.

Comment: Just a word of caution, the `tail` property should be a shared reference across all of the nodes - if it's just a property you'll break your linked list when you attempt to append a node to a node that's not at the tail of the list. If it's a setter that loops through the whole list to update each node's `tail` then your second example will also execute at `O(n)` time.

Comment: Shared reference? I have it as an attribute in my Node class.

Comment: Class attribute is not enough - the moment you assign `tail` to an instance (e.g. `self.tail = new_node`) it gets stored as an instance attribute (in the instances' `__dict__`) which is not shared among other instances. You can use `LinkedListClass.tail = new_node` instead but then the `tail` will be shared among all instances of the `LinkedListClass` so you won't be able to use it for more than one linked list. What you need is to have the `tail` property shared among all nodes of the same list and it has to be a reference - for example, store the reference in some mutable type.

Comment: You're asking the wrong authority in posting here ... yet.  If you want to get an idea of the time complexity, get it empirically: run the algorithms through a series of experiments, and watch the processing time as a function of input size.  These are simple enough that you can track them with a code profiler, or simply time the runs.